# instead of between can we do something better

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

We are using below `condition` in our query

```
AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN NVL( pap.effective_start_date, SYSDATE - 1 ) 
                       AND NVL( pap.effective_end_date, SYSDATE + 1 )
```

How can I rewrite the query without using `BETWEEN`?

Comment: One "better" way would be to ditch the proprietary outer join using `(+)` which even Oracle recommends. But using `>= ` and `<` is typically better with date/time values but as you need a `coalesce()` there won't be the possibility to use an index even with that.

Comment: ya that will definitely remove. can you suggest for between as well please.

Comment: What do you want to achieve removing `between`. As already said, `coalesce` will disable index/partition access, so any transformation will not provide any improvement

Answer (score 0):

If you are only concerned with code writing, Then you can surely try the below code -

```
AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) >= NVL( pap.effective_start_date, SYSDATE - 1 )
AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) <= NVL( pap.effective_end_date, SYSDATE + 1 )
```

Comment: Each task should have a purpose. The question didn't declare the purpose. So equally valid answers are any constant `true` or even semantically constant `true` conditions added to this one.